# CWM or TWRP not supported?

Tags: recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, twrp, lg-g2

I'm trying to install CWM or TWRP for my D801 LG G2 and they both say "device not supported". TWRP doesn't give me any other options, but CWM shows D802 is supported. Can I install that or will it brick my phone?

Also, can I install CM11 with CWM or is that a TWRP only type of thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The "device not supported" message means that you probably downloaded the recovery image for a different device (AT&T's LG G2 "d802", or International LG G2 "d800".)  You can override this check, but it's not recommended, as the devices might be different enough that you could cause irreparable damage to it (a.k.a. "bricking".)

The most current TWRP for T-Mobile's LG G2 (d801) is located [here](http://techerrata.com/browse/twrp2/g2tmo).  I could not find an official ClockworkMod recovery for the d801, but you may want to search appropriate sections on [XDA-Developers forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g2/development-tmobile) for unofficial builds that are compatible with your phone.  Another recovery image according to CM's installation wiki can be downloaded from [here](http://eljef.me/recovery_d801.lok), but must be flashed with [loki_flash](https://github.com/djrbliss/loki/raw/master/bin/loki_flash) tool, as described in the [installation instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_d801).